# Use regex to replace text while stripping newlines and quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

This is now mostly academic as I can achieve the same result other ways, but… it’s been bugging me, and I’m sure is possible somehow with regex.

I want to use PHP’s preg_replace to replace content thus:

```
Content: “String <tag>This is some content, which contains newlines and quotation marks.</tag> and other unrelated content”.

Regex: /<tag>(.*)<\/tag>/sU

Replace: “String of other content, including matched pattern $1”
```

However the problem is, I want to strip out any newlines and/or quotation marks found between the  elements. What regex would allow me to do this?

Comment: Perhaps thiss will get you in the right direction: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/all_about_html_tags.htm Also, there are a lot of topics about this. So: what did you try or what is what you try to achieve? Maybe you are trying something with a regex where a specific php function is built for.. ?

Comment: Yes, it became clear regex alone was unfortunately not the solution, but the problem intrigued me so I wondered if it were possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easy, but possible.

Try this **PHP code**:

```
function myFn($a, $b, $c) {
  $b = preg_replace("!(?:\\\'|[\"\n\r])!", '', $b);
  return "BEGIN " . $b . " END";
}
$s = "abc <tag>def \n ghi 'jkl' mno \"pqr\" stu</tag> vwx";
$s = preg_replace('!(<tag>)(.*?)(</tag>)!ise', 'myFn("$1", "$2", "$3")', $s);
print $s;
```

Output:

```
abc BEGIN def  ghi jkl mno pqr stu END vwx
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/dNvI8).

Comment: To paraphrase, it is possible but not something that one should do… seek an alternative solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

PHPs preg_replace() does a one-pass processing of the subject. You can actually specify an array of patterns and replacements, however only one will match on each part of the subject string. There certainly is no solution using a singel regex, since this problem is not amongst the regular languages. Theoretical computer science teaches that you need a stateful automat for such task. A regex is to primitive.

Answer (score 0):

As arkascha pointed out, this is not really a problem that can easily be done in one pass.

It could be done in one step in Perl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = "blah <tag> foo \"bar \n </tag> baz";

$string =~ s/(?<=\<tag\>)([^<]+)(?=\<\/tag\>)/$_=$1;s|[\n\"]||gs;$_/ges;

print $string;
```

This takes advantage of the fact that Perl lets you use code to generate the replacement string.

I don't know whether something similar could be done in PHP.  This is not a good real-world code design anyway.  But it is fun.